# Operator Overloading = and [] at the same time

Tags: c++, vector

I am implementing my own vector in c++.

This is my Vector class :

```
template <class T>
class Vector
{

    private :
        T *ptr;
        unsigned int numEle;

    public :
        T operator[] (unsigned int index)
        {
            if (index >= numEle)
                return ptr[0];
            else if (index < 0)
                 return ptr[0];
            else
                 return ptr[index];
        }

};
```

What i want to do is overload `=` operator such that when i write

```
  Vector v;
  v[2]=2;
```

It assigns the value 2 to the 2nd index....
Please Help..!!

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with overloading the `operator=()`, what you want to achieve should already work with the `operator[]()` overload.

Comment: There is no need for overloading "=" as you want to use the default behavior for "=" operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make 1 method return a reference to the given index; another a const method returning a const reference to the given index - the latter for reading the elements of type `const Vector&`.

```
T& operator[] (unsigned int index) // make it return a reference.
{
    if (index >= numEle)
        return ptr[0];

    return ptr[index];
};

const T& operator[] (unsigned int index) const // make it return a const reference
{
    if (index >= numEle)
        return ptr[0];

    return ptr[index];
};
```

Notice that `unsigned int` cannot be `< 0` so the second `if` is useless.

The `operator=` is for the case of writing `vector = anotherVector`; it is not needed here.

However if your `T` is a class, it might need the `operator=`.

Comment: But the ptr[index] is a value not a pointer.....to be more clear i am not making an array of vectors.....

Comment: You might need the `operator=` for `T`

Comment: if T is a class then still = can be overloaded simultaneously to both vector and that class rite....??

Comment: Of course, but the `operator=` on vector is for replacing the vector contents with the contents of another, whereas `operator=` on `T` is for replacing 1 element in your vector with another.

Comment: i have assumed that if any user uses my vector class and T is any other user-defined class, then he will write the operator= overload for his class.....

Comment: Yes, you assume right.

Answer (score 6):

It should be

```
T& operator [] (unsigned int index)
```

for your case. Also, I recommend you to write a `const` version of the operator.

```
const T& operator [] (unsigned int index) const
```